# Remove slug and custom post type name from URL

Tags: php, custom-post-types, custom-taxonomy

I have a custom post type "treatment", under this CPT the taxonomy "treatment_category" which forntend slug is "category"

right now the URL for category displaying as follows.

[www.MYDOMAIN.COM/category/practitioner-london/](http://www.MYDOMAIN.COM/category/practitioner-london/)

Just want to remove the slug "category" and  display as

[www.MYDOMAIN.COM/practitioner-london/](http://www.MYDOMAIN.COM/practitioner-london/)

also the post URLs like this

[www.MYDOMAIN.COM/treatment/practitioner-london/dermal-filler-london/](http://www.MYDOMAIN.COM/treatment/practitioner-london/dermal-filler-london/)

also want to change this to as below by removing "treatment"

[www.MYDOMAIN.COM/practitioner-london/dermal-filler-london/](http://www.MYDOMAIN.COM/practitioner-london/dermal-filler-london/)

is this possible.

Comment: You can try plugin https://wordpress.org/plugins/remove-category-url/. For me, I still prefer to keep the category